# Firebase BigQuery export changes: will event parameter "previous_timestamp" disappear?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

At the moment it is possible to get the "previous_timestamp" parameter to every event. I received an Email, that "in the coming weeks" the dataset will follow a new schema. After comparing it to the current schema I discovered, that the parameter "previous_timestamp" is no longer in the [List](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9002261).
Does anyone know if it really will disappear?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thomas, how do you currently use this field?

Comment: At the moment we are just setting up the app analytics, so we do not use it yet. But we thought about using this field to see the time gap for a user triggering the same event by comparing "previous_timestamp" and "timestamp". With "previous_timestamp" disappearing we would have to find a custom solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schema has been [updated](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9002261) to include this field.